# Restart mongodb automatically after killing by OS

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Currently, the mongodb service will be killed by OS sometimes , and then all the related jobs will fail.

How could I run the mongodb as a daemon which can automatically restart after getting killed.

I guess the too many open connections are the reason of being killed by OS

Unfortunely, i couldn't found out where does it come from.

I need a workaround to `restart mongodb automatically`. how could I do ? thanks

>

```
  2015-10-23T08:33:37.770+0900 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.17.2.105:51250 #159375 (5257 connections now open)
  2015-10-23T08:33:37.772+0900 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.17.2.105:51251 #159376 (5258 connections now open)
```

Comment: create a cron job that will check the status after some interval using shell script. But you should find the root cause of service being down instead of workaround

Comment: isn't there any way to restart it automatically, like running some services under `/etc/init/`  thanks

Comment: No, as @Undefined_variable suggest. you have to check manually after fix interval and restart your `mongod` instance if it is stopped.